# Scrolling,Pagination or Load more Technique for UITableView in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, pagination, lazy-loading

Hai i am new to iOS App Development.In my project i am getting 4000 of response data from web service and i need to display it on tableview  But the condition here is I have to display only 30 records initially and once user scroll down I have to load more records.

Comment: In your `willDisplayCell` you can check if the current `indexPath.row` is `dataSourceArray.count - 10`. If it is, then fetch the next number of pages and add the response to the `dataSourceArray`

Comment: http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/8-automatic-uitableview-paging This saved my time

Answer (score 1):

You can manage it with following two ways:
**1) Manually** 
Here what you need to do is, You need to take two `NSMutableArray`, let say **responseArray and tblArray**. From that responseArray contains response of your web service and tblArray will manage `UITableView` count.
By this you can initially show a set of data, for e.g. 10, so `int count = 10`, by adding **first 10 record from responseArray to tblArray** . When user scroll down you can get 11-20 data from responseArray and add them to tblArray using

```
for(int i = 10; i < 20; i++)
{
    [tblArray addObject:[responseArray objectAtIndex:i]]
}
[<your TableView Name> reloadData];
count += 10;
```

**2) Handel From Server Side** 
With this option you can easily handle whole the stuff. 
For this you only need to pass your current count/Paging value to server and server will response you back accordingly.
For example: initially you don't have any record right now. So you can **pass 0 in the web service parameter**.
Once you get the response of that you will have **10 records in response**. Display them in your `UITableView`.
Now when user scroll down you can manage array count here in
 `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`
In the above method you can increase your count value by 1 or you can set it equal to your array count. For now `count += 1` or `count += <yourArrayName>.count`.
After that you again pass the **count value as your web service parameter and you will get next 10 record in your response**. Which you need to append to your array by `[<yourArrayName> arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:<your resposeArray>];`.
Using either way you can get your problem solve. But I personally **recommend** to go with the **2nd option**.

Comment: need help regarding the same

Comment: @DilipTiwari: Please let me know what you need help about?

Comment: i have a JSON response of image and it has 193 data as of now it can be increased in future so currently i want to display only 20 cells at one time and when user reaches at 20th cells and scrolls i want to show another 20 cells below so that image loading will be faster . i want like facebook pagination, i donot want to add pagecount to increment and fetch the value when i call delegate methods. this help i want bro

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a third party library to implement Load More, you could try this

https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh

Manually you could also use `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` to keep track of last visible cell, after which you can append more data in your `dataSource`.